# How to find few minutes older files in perl

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I only want to process files which are last modified 10 minutes ago. I am trying to achieve it like this.

```
for my $file (<${dir}/*csv>_) { 
    if ( -M $file < .0069 ) {
        next;
        }
    else {
         code ...
          }
    }
```

.0069 days have been counted for 10 minutes (10/ (24*60)).  Now files present in the directory which are older than 1 day are identified correctly but any file which is less than 1 day older is recognized incorrectly. for example if file is 23 hours older it is getting processed in if block rather than else.
I guess '-M $file' converting its value to integer (i.e. 0 in this case). Can anyone help here? Thanks

Additional:
Thanks all. I am now trying with file::Stat

```
for my $file (<${dir}/*csv>_) { 
    my $mtime = (stat($file))[9];
    my ctime = time;
    my $time_diff = $ctime - $mtime;

    if ( $time_diff < 600 ) {
        next; }
    else {
        code ...
          }
    }
```

But this is not provoding the accurate results. For file just created $time_diff must be almost zero but it is coming out to be somewhere around -17640. I guess epoch shouldn't be any issue as both times are calculated since epoch.  Where I wrong? ( server time is following IST (+5:30 hrs)

```
}
```

Comment: What does `-M $file` actually return? Could you give some examples of output from that for files you want and files you don't?

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting. Your code will process all files that are modified more than ten minutes ago, which clearly includes files that were modified yesterday.

Comment: @melwil: `-M` returns the (floating point) number of days since the file was modified

Comment: @melwil From the Perl documentation `-M`  Script start time minus file modification time, in days.

Comment: Yes, I think that has been made clear. I wanted to know if the author had considered just looking at what's coming out and why his program is failing based on that.

Answer (score 1):

The code as written should work. There are a few possible reasons why it doesn't. One is of course the familiar old floating point inaccuracy, but that should only hit times close to the ten-minute limit. Another one, which I think is more likely, but you don't give enough context to say for sure, is that the `-M` operator returns differences between the file timestamp and the time when the script started running. This means, for example, that any file created after the script was started will get a negative value from `-M`. If your script is long-running, `-M` is pretty useless. If the filesystem your files reside on is a remote one (NFS or something), clock discrepancy between the server hosting the file system and the server running your script can also mess things up.

I suggest that you rewrite your code to use `stat()` directly. That way you get the times in seconds, so you can deal with integers instead of floats, and you can compare against the current time instead of script start time. Have a look at `perldoc File::stat` to make using `stat()` a bit more readable.

Comment: What do you mean by ***"the familiar old floating point inaccuracy"***? 32-bit floating-point values are accurate to about twelve digits, or about one microsecond per day. That should be quite good enough

Comment: Well, for example, the approximation 0.0069 days that the poster uses is actually 9.936 minutes, not ten. Probably not relevant under the circumstances, but add a few more layers of approximation and it can get significant.

Comment: Ah okay. But that's not *floating point inaccuracy* -- I'd call it *using the wrong number*!

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works:
Trying

```
for my $file (<*>) { 
  print "File $file\n\t -M: " . (-M $file );
  if ( -M $file < .0069 ) {
     print " Doesnt fit\n";
     next;
  } else {
      print " Fits\n";
  }
}
```

in my /tmp directory returned:

```
File config-err-GBOOnR
     -M: 0.0935532407407407 Fits
File cvcd
     -M: 0.0938425925925926 Fits
File kde-gm
     -M: 0.0935300925925926 Fits
File ksocket-gm
     -M: 0.0935300925925926 Fits
File orbit-gm
     -M: 16608.367650463 Fits
File unity_support_test.0
     -M: 0.0935532407407407 Fits
```

But you can also use stat instead:

```
my $mtime = stat($file)[9];
if(time-$mtime > 10*60) {
}
```

should do the job. See

```
perldoc -f stat
```

Comment: thanks.. i have replied with my query in the original question.. :)

Comment: @Ankur: I guess something is wrong on your machine. Add  some debugging code to find the mistake:

`require Data::Dumper;
warn Data::Dumper::Dumper([stat($file), -M $file]);`

should perhaps lead you to your mistake

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux installations which include `perl` probably have the more generalized `find2perl` program.